# nodemon unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am learning node.js and express.js. I installed nodemon but it generated this error:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:151
  async remove(item) {
        ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/watch.js:6:16)
```

npm start works normally but when I run nodemon it generates that error

Comment: Why are you saying that it's nodemon error? Can you be sure that this same error is not coming when you do "nom start"?

Comment: Can you paste little bit more of your code? Where this error might be originating from.

Comment: because this happens when I run nodemon. everything else works fine.

Comment: What version of Node are you running? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363182/how-to-fix-nodemon-async-remove-syntax-error

Comment: yup .. I was running an old version of node. thanks